# Way to up incoming and outgoing mail for a custom mobile app

Tags: ios, cordova

I am used to building apps in larger infrastructures.  In a startup, how do I setup SMTP for a mobile app?  Is there a place I can use for hosting this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do? Your question is a bit unclear. iOS has a dialog you can invoke to send e-mail via the user's e-mail accounts.

Comment: Yes, I have built a new mobile app and am going to put it into the app store for users.  How do I get email working for the app, so the app can send outgoing and incoming emails from the app itself?

Comment: Unless you're writing an e-mail client, I'm not clear on why you'd want to do that. Again, you can invoke the iOS dialog for sending outgoing e-mail. Incoming e-mail can't be accepted by your app, you can't (nor should you) run a mail server on an iOS phone. You'd need a server somewhere accepting the e-mail.

Comment: thanks, so outgoing the phone can already handle, can it send from my domain name? The incoming I would need  a servers somewhere, how do most people handle email for this type of scenerio?  Or perhaps it would be easier to send to their email address they already have setup.

Comment: No, outgoing mail via the iOS mail dialog comes from the user. If you want it from your domain name, you'll need to set up a server that does the actual sending.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible approaches:

1. One option is to not attempt to interface with SMTP/IMAP/POP servers directly in your app. You can, alternatively, send emails from your app via [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), which gives you a standard compose email user interface. This is very easy to do.

   To handle inbound emails you can let the user receive their emails via the standard Mail app (that way users don't have to go to different places to receive their emails). You integrate inbound emails with your app using a [custom URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50). You can then send the user an email using this custom URL scheme, and if they get the mail on their iOS device and have that app installed, when they click on the link they will be taken to your app, passing it information from the URL in the email.

   For example, if you defined a custom URL scheme of `yourapp://`, you can just include a hyperlink to that URL in your email (or text message or your web site), and if the user is on their iOS device, when they click on that link, they'll be taken to your app. If you google "iOS custom URL scheme tutorial", you'll see examples of the plist entries you need to make in your app for it to respond to a custom URL scheme. The [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) reference shows you what sort of changes you need to make to your app delegate to actually pass data in your custom URL to your app.
2. Alternatively, you can (a) sign up with any Internet Service Provider (ISP) that offers mail hosting; (b) write an app that sends email by connecting to that ISP's SMTP server; and (c) retrieve email by connecting to that ISP's IMAP or POP servers. Clearly you'll have to pay fees to the ISP, the quality of your app is linked to the quality of the ISP you partner with (so pick a good one), and you'll have to do your own SMTP/IMAP/POP integration in your app (and you'll have to write your own code to do that or use a third-party library for that, as this is not standard Cocoa Touch functionality). In my opinion, you'd need a pretty compelling business case to go down this road, though it can be done.
3. You could avoid email altogether, and develop a web service for letting the users send and receive messages. (This might make sense if the app is just sending messages between users of your app, for example.) Again, you'll have to contract with an ISP for web hosting, and you'll of course have to undertake the non-trivial exercise of writing your web service code. But this is architecturally cleaner than integrating with SMTP/IMAP/POP servers if the purpose of your app to facilitate communication between users of your app.

You haven't provided enough information for us to assess which approach best suits your situation.